# How to dynamically set popover offset in bootstrap using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

can anybody tell How to dynamically set popover offset position  in bootstrap using Jquery. If user clicked(pressed) button I need to shows popover  placement bottom  start from left button edges

Thanks

Comment: The docs cover this. See the `placement` property: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/#options

Comment: Please share your code...